# Is there a way to monitor real time usage of Firebase query in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

So I am currently trying to make the code of my app a little more efficient because of increasing user counts the costs of Firebase are rising very rapidly. I figured that in development I made a few poor query decisions, therefore "unintended" usage of data transfer. Whatever now I am trying to develop better solutions to that. But for that really to work I would need some kind of way to actually monitor how much less/more data a query uses. Is there currently a way in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database comes with several tools to [monitor aggregate data usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/monitor-usage) and to [monitor performance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/monitor-performance). To see the specific access patterns over a shorter period of time, consider using the [database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile).